# HTML table with 2 lines of cells in a row

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am working with a HTML table and was wondering if a layout like shown in my screenshot are possible?

I know i can do this with `<div>`, but would prefer to keep the table formatting.

[image: HTML table]

Comment: Why not use two rows?  What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?  It's not clear why this *needs* to use a `<table>` when this layout doesn't appear to be tabular.

Comment: You will have to use an extra tr, otherwise it doesn't make sense that one td gets it's own row (tr means table row, afterall).

Comment: @David. There will be multiple rows and I need each <tr> to be the same wrapper for all child <td> because of DOM manipulation. jQuery Sortable etc. Suggestion by Md. Rakibul Islam is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what you wanted. Keep in mind that usually this is not how you should structure your html (Shifting a table cell into next row).

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

table{
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 5px;
}

tr{
    border: 1px solid blue;
    padding: 5px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

td{
    height: 50px;
    flex-basis: 24%;
    border: 1px solid green;
    margin: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

td:last-child{
    flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Table cells do not wrap within a row, so you would need a new row.  Within that row, the table cell would then span the other columns.

Tables are for presenting tabular data (correlated rows and columns).
If that is not your purpose (such as layout), then a different method would be preferable.  Flexbox or grid would work nicely, depending on the use case.

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
  padding: .25em;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <caption>Caption should be included for accessibility</caption>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4">Spans all 4 columns</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
<table>
```

Comment: There will be multiple rows and I need each <tr> to be the same wrapper for all child <td> because of DOM manipulation. jQuery Sortable etc.

Comment: In that case, you probably shouldn't use a table.  What you're describing breaks the paradigm (or there's a way to improve your implementation for sortable, etc).  If you're breaking semantics in order to get code to work, you should fix the code instead.